# Editor.js How to save editor content

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, editorjs

## The question

https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/issues/2212

This is the link I posted.
I get an error as per this link. What can I do to fix this problem?

I looked for a site that might be helpful but didn't find much.